# Unzip files and move to a destination folder depending on the filename

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I am trying to move files within the zip folders. The names of the Zip Folders changes every months.

1. OH_M7_AEE.zip
2. OH_M7_AOP.zip
3. OH_M7_AIP.zip

The zip folders have subfolders called **GM7_AAA_files** which also changes on a monthly basis.

What I would like to do is move the csv files within the subfolders to their destination folders.

So in **OH_M7_AEE.zip** there is a subfolder called **GM7_AAA** and I would like to move the **109EM_Main.csv** to folder **Test2** and **109EM_Main.csv** to Folder **Test2**.

So far I just managed to move the subfolder with the csv files not what I exactly want.

```
$path = "\\networkdrive\2. Digital\Test"

$destination = "\\networkdrive\2. Digital\Test2"

$shell_app= New-Object -com shell.application

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -filter *.zip -recurse

foreach($file in $files) {

  $zip_file = $shell_app.namespace($file.FullName)

  $copyHere = $shell_app.namespace($destination)

  $copyHere.Copyhere($zip_file.items())

}
```

Hope I made sense and apologies if I didn't. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: It doesn't really make too much sense to be honest. You say you want to move the same file (109EM_Main.csv) to two different folders. If you show the folder structure of the zip as well as the folder structure you want to end up with, it'll probably be easier to help you

Comment: Hi Mathias. Your right and apologies I made the changes to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand your problem. You can't really manipulate or filter items inside the Zip file very well because you are dealing with COM objects and not files directly. Instead of trying to figure out a way to manipulate the COM objects to filter out the csv files from the zip file directly, instead I say, extract the whole zip file to a temp location (a folder that exists), then copy/move out the files to you destination.

```
#Source (Where Zip files containing CSV files are)
$path = "\\networkdrive\2. Digital\Test"

#Temp Zip Destination (Folder where we can temporarily extract the zip file)
$TempZip = "\\networkdrive\2. Digital\ExtractedZip"

#Destination (Folder where CSV's go)
$destination = "\\networkdrive\2. Digital\Test2"

$shell_app= New-Object -com shell.application

#Get Zip files
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -filter *.zip -recurse

#Loop through all zip files
foreach($file in $files) {

  #Open Zip File
  $zip_file = $shell_app.namespace($file.FullName)

  #Loop through all subfolders inside Zip file
  foreach($item in $zip_file.items())
  {
    #Extract files to Temporary destination
    $shell_app.Namespace($TempZip).Copyhere($item)
  }

  #Get all the *.CSV files (not folders) from the temporary folder and move to destination
  Get-ChildItem $TempZip -Filter *.CSV -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $destination

  #Clear out the files from the temp location
  Remove-Item $TempZip\* -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: this copies the subfolder with the csv files. I don't want the subfolder I just need the csv files copied.

Comment: Ah I think that I understand what you are trying to accomplish. The issue is that you can't really (easily) filter the stuff inside the Zip file because you are dealing with COM objects, and they are not easy to deal with. The simpler method is to extract everything to a temporary folder that you create, and then it's easy to copy/move/filter items out of it and to your destination.